# MySQL UPDATE with JOIN failing

Tags: sql, mysql

```
update  loan  l  
inner join (
        select LoanId, sum(Amount) as Amount 
        from    loanpayment  
        where   LoanId = pLoanId  
        )  as  lp on l.Id = lp.LoanId 

set  l.CurBalance = OriginalAmount + TermMonths *(OriginalAmount * MonthlyRate/100) 
                        - coalesce(lp.Amount,0) 
where   l.Id = pLoanId   ;
```

The `CurBalance` is not being updated when I change the `TermMonths`.  Am I missing something ?

Thanks. I am on mysql 7 and 8.

Comment: Is lp.Amount NULL, a single or multiple values? For it to work it must never be multiple values.

Comment: shouldn't where   l.Id = pLoanId   be where l.Id = lp.LoanId ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try running a simplified version of the query to see if it updates the `CurBalance` correctly. For example, try updating `CurBalance` to a fixed value without involving the TermMonths or other calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I think P.Salmon is right.
In the subquery try to add a GROUP BY LoanId.